# Supporting a single pipe with a custom shell in C

Tags: c, shell, unix, pipe

I was implementing a custom shell in C which required me to implement simple commands like echo,ls etc and input/output redirection.My project is done but when I was searching for some tips I found that there is a book which asked for a custom shell to support a single pipe so I tried to code that.First of all I tried to make a pipe in a normal c program to make sure that I can implement pipes.I was able to do it but somehow I have difficulties in doing it in my custom shell.

```
 int mypipe[2];
    if (pipe(mypipe) == -1) {
        perror("Pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }
  firstchild=fork();
    if (firstchild == 0) { // first child
        close(mypipe[1]); //Closing  the output  of pipe
        read1 = read(mypipe[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));   
        printf(" %s\n", buffer);
        myDate(child1, child2, result);
        write(mypipe2[1], result, strlen(result)+1);
    } else {
        secondchild=fork(); //Creating second child
        if(secondchild == 0) { //2nd child
            read1 = read(mypipe2[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));  
            printf(" %s\n",  buffer);
```

I believe this code is correct since I could send time from child1 to child 2 and print it with child 2 but I cannot apply the same concept to my own shell where there is a parent who is waiting for child to terminate.And there are so many execv in my code which confuses me about what will happen in the future.And I only created one child process in my custom shell so I believe I need to create another which again is another problem for me since it will be hard for me to synchronize it with exec vs.Here is a small part of my own shell.

```
}if(!strcmp(args[0] ,"clear")){  
             execv("/usr/bin/clear",args);

          }if(!strcmp(args[0] ,"env")){  
             execv("/usr/bin/env",args);
            }
            perror("Error");            
           exit(1);  //Failure
      }else{
        do{
           waitpid(child,&status,WUNTRACED);
               }while(!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
```

As you can guess else statement is coming from if(child=0).I would be really glad if someone can show me how to support a single pipe in a structure like this.My ultimate purpose is trying to support multiple pipes but I think I can figure it out myself when I see a single pipe

Comment: Do you have the rest of your own custom shell to handle pipes? It appears you are handling the arguments passed into the shell and you are setting up to `fork()` the process but I do not see that here. Can we see your implementation of the `fork()` process?